# Why does printf generate an extra function when using MinGW-w64?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, mingw, mingw-w64

Looking at the assembly output by GCC with -O2 I see that if I use `printf` GCC will create a function named, for example, `_Z6printfPKcz`, which then calls `__mingw_vprintf`. What is the purpose for this indirection? Why doesn't `printf` translate directly to a call to `__mingw_printf`? This is the same for the other related functions, such as sprintf.

Edit:

For the record, I know what name mangling is and how it works. My question is why is the compiler generating the function in the first place, a function which does nothing but forward the arguments to __mingw_vprintf, when it could simply call __mingw_printf directly and save the unnecessary indirection.

In other words, why should this:

```
printf("%d\n", var);
```

compile to this:

```
_Z6printfPKcz:
    sub rsp, 56
    mov QWORD PTR 72[rsp], rdx
    lea rdx, 72[rsp]
    mov QWORD PTR 80[rsp], r8
    mov QWORD PTR 88[rsp], r9
    mov QWORD PTR 40[rsp], rdx
    call    __mingw_vprintf
    add rsp, 56
    ret

main:
    ...
    call    _Z6printfPKcz
    ...
```

when this would suffice

```
main:
    ...
    call    __mingw_printf
    ...
```

Comment: Looks like the standard way `printf` is implemented, by calling [`vprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf)

Comment: Well yeah, I can see that. My question is why. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 5):

`_Z6printfPKcz` is just the mangled name of `printf` - search "name mangling" for more information on that. It's the actual printf function.

`__mingw_vprintf` is an internal function which `printf` calls - there's no requirement that `printf` doesn't call another function to do its work. Maybe `__mingw_vprintf` handles all the formatting and printing, and `printf` is written like this:

```
int printf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, fmt);
    int result = __mingw_vprintf(fmt, va);
    va_end(va);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: "Search 'name mangling'"? Why not implement the [name mangling rules](http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling) in your head and demangle mentally? :-)

Comment: I know what name mangling is. My question is why is a standard library function being implemented inside of the assembly file generated by my code instead of simply being linked. The function doesn't do anything at all but forward to __mingw_vprintf. There already exists a __mingw_printf function, so why not call that directly and avoid the unnecessary code and the unnecessary function call.

Answer (score 2):

`_pZ6printfPKcz` is a C++ mangled name for a function that has the signature `printf(char const*, ...)` - in other words, the actual printf function. Which, it would appear is implemented by calling another function. Since there are half a dozen different variants of `printf` (with different types of output, such as output to a file, output to a string, output to console, etc), it makes sense to have a single, "do printf" function - which in this case appears to be `__mingq_vprintf`. Since a printf implementation is a few thousand lines of code, we don't really want to duplicate it 6 or so times for all the different variants (I know, because at work I've been implementing a version of printf for OpenCL - it's a pretty complicated function, you DEFINITELY don't want to have the actual code several times over).

You can see the exact definition of `printf` in the "stdio.h" here:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/browser/trunk/mingw-w64-headers/crt/stdio.h?rev=5437#L283

As to exactly why they do this, it's really something you have to ask the developers of mingw - but my assumption would be that they are trying to keep the number of different variants down - for example `__mingw_vprintf` is also used to implement the actual `vprintf` variant, so that's "half as many variants already".

The extra layering also allows the printf to be switched between narrow (ASCII) and wide characters (so called UNICODE), as can be seen by the macros here:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/browser/trunk/mingw-w64-crt/stdio/mingw_pformat.h?rev=3972#L69

And you'll hate the mingw developers even more when you realize that __mingw_vprintf turns into just another layer of call:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/browser/trunk/mingw-w64-crt/stdio/mingw_vprintf.c?rev=2296#L51

However, in the whole scheme of a printf implementation, like I said in my comment, it's very small amounts of overhead - the `_pformat` code is a good 2000 lines long:

http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mingw-org-wsl/ci/21762bb4a1bd0c88c38eead03f59e8d994349e83/tree/misc/src/libcrt/stdio/pformat.c

(Which is much smaller than the glibc implementation)

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me. As I said, if it simply inserted a call to __mingw_printf instead then there would be 0 superfluous  code and duplication, and one less function call.

Comment: But `__mingw_vprintf` is presumably not a straightforward replacement, but has a different set of parameters. Note that it's called `__mingw_vprintf`, not `__mingw_printf` - this typically means that it takes a `va_list` as an argument, rather than having a `...` argument. Most likely this is done through an inline definition of `printf` to call `__mingw_vprintf`. And given the size and complexity of a real `printf` implementation, I'm pretty sure one extra level of call and a few shufflings of arguments won't make one iota of difference.

Comment: But there **is** a `__mingw_printf` function, which I can call directly and avoid the whole `__mingw_vprintf` indirection.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know.

Answer (score 1):

Printf fails to be inlined in this specific case. If inline fails, compiler have to create an explicit  function body. Usual behavior without indirection is explained by successful inline.

Answer (score 1):

There are three things to be realized here and none of the answers contains all three of them (at the moment at least).

1. `_Z6printfPKcz` is the mangled name of `printf`. See [immibis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23576010/341970).
2. There are several variants of the `printf` functions and one or only a few functions *implementing* the functionality. The latter function(s), whose name start with `__`, do the heavy lifting and are internal to the implementation; the functions exposed to the user don't do any significant work, they basically just forward the call either to another forwarding function or to the implementing function. See [Mats Petersson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23576031/341970).
3. Inlining of the forwarding function failed in your case. See [Basilevs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23576291/341970).

I suspect, based on your comments, that your real question is why the inlining failed, why the implementation isn't called directly, without any overhead. Good question, I don't see any valid technical reason for that.

I know that gcc (at least on Linux) has the tendency not to inline functions if link-time optimization is not used, even if both the function body (implementation) and the call site is in the same translation unit (in the same source file).

**Try to enable link-time optimization. See `-flto` among the [Options That Control Optimization](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).** It is very likely that the call will be inlined with link time optimization; that functions seems to be a good candidate for inlining.

---

**UPDATE:** I cannot test mingw; here are my tests on Linux. This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  printf("%d\n", argc);
}
```

results in the following assembly with optimizations disabled `-O0`:

```
    [...]
    call    printf
    [...]
```

That is, the call to `printf` is not inlined. However, already at `-O1` I get:

```
    [...]
    call    __printf_chk
    [...]
```

which means that the call to `printf` was inlined and I am directly calling the underlying implementation. It didn't even require link time optimization. You only need to motivate the compiler to do the inlining.

Giving it some thought: The compiler may not inline functions at compile time that are in the C *runtime* because they are supposed to be accessed at *runtime*. But it definitely inlines the wrapper function already at `-O1`.

As to why a particular version of a compiler on a particular platform fails to inline a particular function, well... If you think it is a performance hit in your application, try to submit a bug report. If I were you, I wouldn't worry to much about it, the IO will cost you a lot more time than that extra function call due to the failed inline.

Comment: Adding `-flto` didn't remove the extra function code or the call to it. If I compile the code here: http://gcc.godbolt.org/ it will simply put in a `call printf` and no extra functions are in the assembly output.

Comment: @Chris_F Well, it does on my machine already at `-O1`. Please read the updated answer.